# Cannot debug remote JS file in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, microsoft-edge

I am having a Microsoft Edge specific JS error, which is in a callback that jQuery uses. The callback lives in a file that is pulled in remotely from a CDN. When I open Edge's debugger and try to open that file, it does not appear in the list, and neither do any other remote JS files, only files that are local to the website.

I can in fact find these remote files in the chrome debugger, is this an Edge bug or is there some kind of setting I do not know about that hides remote files?